# Maximise profits using probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A gambler on the streets has 2 loaded coins with probability 0.7 of getting tails, and 1 fair coin with a probability of getting heads or tails.

If you get 3 heads, you win 10 dollars. If you get 2 heads (not in a row), you win 5 dollars, if you get 2 heads (in a row), you win 1 dollar. Otherwise you win nothing.

If you can play the game many times, is there a particular arrangement of **coins to maximise my profits?
How would I prove that there is no such arrangement?**

Comment: @the_candyman Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Sorry, I've read the question more carefully. Please, read my answer.

Comment: The intuitive argument, which is supported by the_candyman's formal answer is that if you are going to get 2H's and 1T, it is best if the T is the middle toss.  Therefore, don't have the fair coin tossed second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the arrangement LLF. We have that:

$P(HHH) = 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.5 = 0.045$ (three heads in a row).

$P(HTH) = 0.3 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.5 = 0.105$ (two heads, not in a row).

$P(HHT)+P(THH) = 0.3 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.5 + 0.7 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.5 = 0.150$ (two heads in a row).

The expected win is:

$$10\cdot 0.045 + 5 \cdot 0.105 + 1 \cdot 0.150 = 1.125.$$

Now, consider the arrangement  LFL. We have that:

$P(HHH) = 0.3 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.3 = 0.045.$

$P(HTH) = 0.3 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.3 = 0.045.$

$P(HHT)+P(THH) = 0.3 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.7 + 0.7 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.3 = 0.210.$

The expected win is:

$$10\cdot 0.045 + 5 \cdot 0.045 + 1 \cdot 0.210 = 1.125 = 0.885.$$

Finally, consider the arrangement FLL. We have that:

$P(HHH) = 0.5 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 = 0.045.$

$P(HTH) = 0.5 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.3 = 0.105.$

$P(HHT)+P(THH) = 0.5 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7 + 0.5 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 = 0.150.$

The expected win is:

$$10\cdot 0.045 + 5 \cdot 0.105 + 1 \cdot 0.150 = 1.125 = 1.125.$$

This means that both LLF and FLL maximize your expected payoff... so don't use the fair coin for the second toss!!! :D

---

Addition

As a side remark, we observe that the probability to win something, i.e.

$$P = P(HHH) + P(HTH) + (P(HHT)+P(THH))$$

is independent on the arrangement, and it is equal to $0.3$. Let's give a name to each coin. Let's that one loaded coin is A, the other is B and fair one is C. First of all, notice that, for example:

$$P(A = H, B = T, C = T) = P(B = T, C = T, A = H) = ...,$$
i.e. it is not important the order.

Secondly, tosses are independent, i.e.
$$P(A = H, B = T, C = T)  = P(A=H)P(B=T)P(C=T).$$

Last assumption: let $P(A=T) = P(B=T) = t$ (in the specific case, $t=0.7$).

Observe that:

$$P = P(\text{probability to get at least two H}) = \\
~\\
= P(A=H, B=H, C=H) \\
+ P(A=H, B=H, C=T) \\
+ P(A=T, B=H, C=H) \\
+ P(A=H, B=T, C=H) =\\
~\\
= P(A=H)P(B=H)P(C=H) \\
+ P(A=H)P(B=H)P(C=T) \\
+ P(A=T)P(B=H)P(C=H) \\
+ P(A=H)P(B=T)P(C=H) =\\
~\\
= (1-t)(1-t)0.5 
+ (1-t)(1-t)0.5 
+ t(1-t)0.5 
+ (1-t)t0.5 =\\
~\\
= (1-t)^2 + 2 \cdot 0.5 t(1-t) = (1-t)^2 + t(1-t) = (1-t)((1-t)+t)) = 1-t.
$$

Since $t=0.7$, then $P = 1-0.7= 0.3$.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that the sum of probabilities for the 3 arrangements is always 0.3, but it's not intuitive to me why that's the case?